# "Object already exists error" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

My Javascript program is creating "Object already exists" errors on both Google Chrome and on Firefox. **What kind of mistake could trigger this error message?** I am having a hard time debugging this without knowing what the error means.

Comment: what line does it give you the error on?

Comment: try running your script thru jslint

Comment: The code might be from the Object Storage API:http://uxebu.com/blog/2011/04/27/creating-a-persistent-dojo-object-store/. Are you using that?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: JSLint doesn't accuse anything. I don't know the line because the script is being loaded in a funcky way that confuses the browsers. (This is why I am asking the question here - if someone knows what the message means I might be able to narrow down on the problem)

Comment: @pimvdb: Not using that. Do you think this message comes from within Dojo (instead of being a general javascript error?)

Comment: `throw "Object already exists"` <-- that kind of mistake. I would -1 for such an unclear question with no diagnostic information, but have no votes.

Comment: Posting a program/parts would have helped immensely. -1 indeed.

Comment: @missingno: Searching Chromium's source reveals no code where that text is literally thrown. That link, however, does.

Comment: @pimvdb: I misread you original comment. Can you repost it as an answer now so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your comment:

All JavaScript is 'open source' (although it can be minified etc), so you can simply search for that exact string. The only result I got that is used as an error thrown is this: http://uxebu.com/blog/2011/04/27/creating-a-persistent-dojo-object-store/.

```
store.add = function(object, options){
    // Get the id
    var id = options && options.id || object.id;

    // Check if something exists under the given
    // id -- StorageJS always returns null when
    // there's no data for a certain key.
    if(storage.get(id) !== null){
        throw new Error("Object already exists"); // <-- did it somehow get here?
    }

    // We're save to go now! So hand over the
    // request to the put() method.
    store.put(object, options);
};
```

Comment: For completeness: this was a bug on a caching routine of mine - if two requests happened too quickly both would latter try to `add` the result. A workaround is using the `put` method instead.

Comment: All Javascript is not open source, but the application in question is searchable by the author

Answer (score 1):

Next time, try using a debugger to break on the exception

Comment: How do I do it if the exception gets caught? All I see is a console.error message.

Comment: most debuggers will let you trap at the throw, and choose between caught and uncaught exceptions.  Only works for exceptions though (as in this case)  I don't know of any way to trap if the code only calls console.error without an exception